# What grind to use for a Phin (Vietnamese Coffee Maker)?

Tags: coffee-machines

I got a phin at a local vietnamese market, and I will be grinding my own beans. Should the grind be fine or coarse or somewhere in the middle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a *phin*, most websites recommend using a grind that you would use for a standard drip machine or a grind that is slightly coarser. Because every *phin* is different, it is necessary to experiment with the grind and find the result that fits your tastes best.

For someone who cannot drink strong coffee, it is best to err on the side of caution and make their grind slightly coarser and adjust to a finer grind slowly. The best taste profile will be found this way.

**Useful resources:**

- [Coffee Geek Phin Guide for Iced Coffee](http://coffeegeek.com/guides/vietnameseiced)
- [Trung Nguyen Online Phin Guide](http://www.trung-nguyen-online.com/brewing-coffee-phin.html)